# Implementing server-side file copy with Paramiko SFTP: Need guidance on custom extensions

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am currently working on a project that involves server-side file copy operations using Paramiko's SFTP on the server side.
I am seeking guidance on how to implement server-side file copy operations with Paramiko. Specifically, I want to add a custom extension or hook to Paramiko that supports a "copy-file" operation.

**Details:**

- **Using Paramiko as a server**
- **Paramiko Version:** 3.3.0
- **Python Version:** 3.9.11
- **Operating System:** Windows 11
- **SSH Server:** OpenSSH v9.4.0

**Observations:**

I have explored the Paramiko documentation and examples, but I couldn't find clear guidance on implementing server-side file copy operations. I attempted to modify the `extension_pairs` in `paramiko/sftp.py` (line 161) to ["copy-file", "md5,sha1"], but it doesn't seem to be recognized. I suspect this is definitely not be the correct approach, and I'm looking for guidance on the proper way to add a custom extension.

here's what I think the useful part of the log of client side to represent it's not working

```
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug2: Remote version: 3
debug2: Unrecognised server extension "copy-data"
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
debug2: Sending SSH2_FXP_REALPATH "."
debug3: Sent message fd 6 T:16 I:1
debug3: SSH2_FXP_REALPATH . -> /
sftp> cp foo bart
Server does not support copy-data extension
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I add a custom extension or hook to Paramiko to support server-side file copy operations?
2. Are there existing hooks or methods that I can leverage for this purpose?

Thanks to anyone who can guide me on the right path or provide insights into implementing server-side file copy with Paramiko.

This question is also asked on github issue: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/2336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paramiko `SFTPServer` class does not seem to have any mechanism to implement custom extensions.

All you can do is to override the `_process` method and handle the `t == CMD_EXTENDED` on your own. But you will have to implement all (both) existing extensions again.

Something like:

```
class MySFTPServer(SFTPServer):
    def _process(self, t, request_number, msg):
        if t == CMD_EXTENDED:
            # Copy of CMD_EXTENDED implementation from SFTPServer._process
            tag = msg.get_text()
            if tag == "check-file":
                self._check_file(request_number, msg)
            elif tag == "posix-rename@openssh.com":
                oldpath = msg.get_text()
                newpath = msg.get_text()
                self._send_status(
                    request_number, self.server.posix_rename(oldpath, newpath)
                )
            elif tag == "copy-file":
                oldpath = msg.get_text()
                newpath = msg.get_text()
                # Your copy-file implementation
                # ... 
            else:
                self._send_status(request_number, SFTP_OP_UNSUPPORTED)
        else:
            super(SFTPServer, self)._process(t, request_number, msg)
```

*(untested)*

And similarly you need to reimplement `_send_server_version` to announce `copy-file` support. What you have tried already, but with wrong syntax. It's not obvious to me, what the right syntax is though. Maybe:

```
extension_pairs = [["check-file", "md5,sha1"], ["copy-data", "1"]]
```

---

Though note that the OpenSSH `sftp` client does not support the `copy-file` extension. It supports the [`copy-data`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00#section-7).